# Select max value from varchar column of access 2010 table

Tags: database, select, max

i am trying to retrieve the largest number from a varchar column that includes both numbers and strings. An example of the data I'm working with:

R_No
102
w
103
105
x
106

I need to return the largest number (106 in this case) from the column while ignoring the non-numeric values of w and x.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT MAX(colname) FROM tablename WHERE NOT colname REGEXP '[a-z]';